# How binary numbers are evaluated for true or false?

Tags: c, binary, boolean

if i write

```
PORTA =0b00000001;
PORTB =0b00000000;
PORTC =0b11111111;
PORTD =0b10100110;
if(PORTA){
//will this block be true?if yes then why and how it is evaluated
}
if(PORTB){
//smae here,to check true or false.
}
if(PORTC){
//if true then why or false,why?
}
if(PORTD){
//same
}
```

if above statement are wrong then how to check the status of a port?

Comment: `0` is false, everything else true.

Comment: What does "check the status of a port" mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @interjay actually what i want to know is that either a port is true or false.in my code,i have written,PORTC=0b11111111; then i used if(!PINC) it comes always false and when i write it like this if(~PINC)then it always comes true,i'm confused what to do with it

Comment: Unless you explain what you mean by "a port is true or false", that comment doesn't help much.

Comment: @interjay if all bits of a port is 1 then it will be true if anyone of them become 0 then false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in C, any non-zero number will evaluate to true. If you want to check the value of a specific bit in your port, use the binary-AND operator `&`. Note: Logical AND, `&&`, and binary AND, `&`, are not the same thing.

In your question, only PORTB will evaluate to false.

Comment: that means binary number are first converted to decimal and then compared to 0?

Comment: There is no difference if you write 0b00000001 or 0x01 or 1 in your code, it will yield the same representation in machine code. Only zero (0, 0x00, 0b00000000 etc.) will evaluate to false.